# Hardwired secret key in public / private key encryption

Tags: functional-encryption

I am new to cryptography and I need to know some details about the hardwired keys.

Taking as an example the paper ["Multi-Input Functional Encryption"](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/727.pdf), a key is hardwired in the description of the key generation scheme.

Is this technique related to encryption schemes or it is a form of circuit construction?

Answer (score 1):

“Hardwiring” an input into a (say, Boolean) circuit usually means taking a circuit $C$ with two inputs $x\in\{0,1\}^n$, $y\in\{0,1\}^m$ and then *fixing* the inputs corresponding to $y$. This gives the circuit $C_y$ that for every $x$ returns $C(x,y)$ [AB]. Thus, hardwiring is more about circuits and has nothing to do with encryption schemes.

In the example of multi-input functional encryption, the circuit $\mathsf{G}_f$ can be seen as a function that takes a master secret key and $n$ ciphertexts as input. By hardwiring a particular $\mathsf{MSK}$, you are fixing the first input to the circuit $\mathsf{G}_f$ to this $\mathsf{MSK}$.

[AB]: Arora and Barak. [Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach](http://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the "circuits" are more of an abstraction as an encryption scheme, and not specific physical circuits.  They are specifying a logic map, such as for Yao's Garbled Circuits.

An approachable introduction is here:  http://web.mit.edu/sonka89/www/papers/2017ygc.pdf